# qooxdoo qx.ui.form.VirtualComboBox key value pairs

Tags: javascript, data-binding, qooxdoo

I would like to know if it is there a prefered way to use key,value pairs in a qooxdoo qx.ui.form.VirtualComboBox. I would like the name to be set in the textbox but when requested the id should be returned. All the examples for this widget I have seen use just the value. I am posting the code how I am approaching the problem but I would like to know if there is a better/prefered way using data binding. So far every time I need the value or the key I loop through the model to find a match. Here is the playground example: http://tinyurl.com/neyfwva

```
//John is set for testing purposes
var myJSONObject = {"personal": [
        {"name": "Martin", "id": "1", "age": "32"},
        {"name": "Horst", "id": "2", "age": "55"},
        {"name": "Peter", "id": "3", "age": "23"},
        {"name": "John", "id": "2", "age": "40"}  ]
};

var jsonmodel = qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel(myJSONObject);

var comboBox = new qx.ui.form.VirtualComboBox(jsonmodel.getPersonal());
comboBox.setLabelPath("name");

comboBox.setDelegate({bindItem : function(controller, item, id) {
  controller.bindProperty("name", "label", null, item, id);
  controller.bindProperty("id", "model", null, item, id);
}});


this.getRoot().add(comboBox);

//#################################################################
//-->> get "ID" from selected value
var button1 = new qx.ui.form.Button("get ID from selectbox");
this.getRoot().add(button1,
{
  left : 20,
  top  : 50
});
button1.addListener("execute", function(e) {
  var model = comboBox.getModel();
  var selection= null;

  for(var i = 0, l = model.getLength(); i < l; i++){
    if(model.getItem(i).getName() === comboBox.getValue()){
      selection = model.getItem(i);
      break;
    }
  }

  if(selection){
  alert(selection.getId());
  }
});
//#################################################################

//#################################################################
//-->> set value "Horst" by giving id
var button2 = new qx.ui.form.Button("set ID -2- (also Horst)");
this.getRoot().add(button2,
{
  left : 200,
  top  : 50
});
button2.addListener("execute", function(e) {
  var model = comboBox.getModel();
  var selection = null;

  for(var i =0, l = model.getLength(); i < l; i++){
    if(model.getItem(i).getId() === "2"){
      selection = model.getItem(i);
      break;
    }
  }

  if(selection){
  comboBox.setValue(selection.getName());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qx.ui.form.VirtualComboBox`'s child control `dropdown` has normal selection data array. Even though Qooxdoo's API reference and docs are very good and thorough, the advice for such cases is *source code is your documentation* (you can go straight to the method's source code from the API reference by following *View Source* links). Qooxdoo's code is as good and comprehensible.

Here's [modified snippet](http://tinyurl.com/op8w3ld):

```
var data = {"personal": [
  {"name": "Martin", "id": "1", "age": "32"},
  {"name": "Horst", "id": "2", "age": "55"},
  {"name": "Peter", "id": "3", "age": "23"},
  {"name": "John", "id": "2", "age": "40"}  
]};

var model = qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel(data);

var comboBox = new qx.ui.form.VirtualComboBox(model.getPersonal());
comboBox.setLabelPath("name");

this.getRoot().add(comboBox);

var getButton = new qx.ui.form.Button("Get id");
this.getRoot().add(getButton, {'left': 20, 'top': 50});

getButton.addListener("execute", function() 
{
  var selection = comboBox.getChildControl('dropdown').getSelection();
  if(selection.getLength())
  {
    this.debug('Here is your id', selection.getItem(0).getId());  
  }
}, this);

var setButton = new qx.ui.form.Button("Set id:2");
this.getRoot().add(setButton, {'left': 200, 'top': 50});

setButton.addListener("execute", function() 
{
  // don't replace selection object as it's used internally
  var selection = comboBox.getChildControl('dropdown').getSelection();
  selection.push(model.getPersonal().getItem(1));
}, this);
```

## Update

If you need to select an item by `id` or another item's attribute, `qx.data.Array` won't help you directly because it's an array, not a dictionary. You have to options:

Pre-calculate `id -> index` mapping and use it later:

```
var mapping = data['personal'].reduce(function(result, item, index)
{
  result[item['id']] = index;
  return result;
}, {});
var selection = model.getPersonal().getItem(mapping['2']);
```

Or filter the data array on demand:

```
var selection = model.getPersonal().filter(function(item)
{
  return item.getId() == '2';
});
```

If you have big list and frequent selection then the former is preferable.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wandered through the documentation and source and the mailing list. Although the documentation is indeed great and the source is almost self documenting, the workings of select type objects have not clicked for me yet. Thanks again.

Comment: But still I would like to know how to set the item with  id : 2 not just the second item.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Just for completeness, for anyone else who may stumble to this question here is the full working code http://tinyurl.com/o48kw8u

Comment: @voger Forgot to mention, you can use `qx.data.Array.prototype.append` and (optionally) `qx.data.Array.prototype.removeAll` to set new selection: http://tinyurl.com/q83sv6o